# Allow white space in current regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to allow whites space in my regex. For some reason this expression will not allow white space. Here is my current regex

```
preg_match( "/^[A-Za-z0-9?.,-=$@!&%';:)(_\s]+$/", $value )
```

Comment: It match whitespaces https://regex101.com/r/cA3pT1/1

Comment: Does it work when you change the `\s` to a single space? Your GREP parser may not recognize the combo as "all whitespace" inside a character class.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the white space you try to match is not in the ascii range. (for example the non-breakable space). So you can try to add the u modifier to extend the `\s` character class to all the unicode whitespaces *(by default `\s` contains only ascii whitespaces)*.

So try this:

```
preg_match( "/^[A-Za-z0-9?.,-=$@!&%';:)(_\s]+$/u", $value )
```

or this:

```
preg_match( "/(*UCP)(*UTF8)^[A-Za-z0-9?.,-=$@!&%';:)(_\s]+$/", $value )
```

Note: I suggest you to perform clever tests to be sure that whitespaces are really the problem.
Note2: this pattern matches exactly the same thing, but it uses character ranges (take a look at the ascii table) and the case insensitive modifier `i`:

```
preg_match( "/^[!$-'(),-=?@-Z_\s]+$/ui", $value )
```

Comment: `(*UCP)` without UTF mode doesn't work. http://ideone.com/HRiFW3 Actually, when you are using PCRE from PHP, there is no need to concern yourself with `(*UCP)`. When you specify `u` flag, [PCRE_UCP is set in PHP wrapper automatically if the library is compiled with support](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/bf59acdea75cf13d179f10ce89d296a30f38676d/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c#L364). If you are not in UTF mode, you can only match one code unit (UTF-8 code unit = 1 byte) in character class.

Comment: @nhahtdh: indeed, I have never notice that because it always worked (for a bad reason) during my tests.

Answer (score 0):

It does match whitespace:

```
preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9?.,-=$@!&%';:)(_\s]+$/", '   '); // true
preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9?.,-=$@!&%';:)(_\s]+$/", 'a a'); // true
preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9?.,-=$@!&%';:)(_\s]+$/", 'aaa'); // true
preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9?.,-=$@!&%';:)(_\s]+$/", 'a*a'); // false
```